# Upload an object by streaming the contents of a file AWS SDK PHP 2

Tags: php, upload, amazon-s3

I am to newbie to amazon s3. I downloaded zip into my project and unzipped it. Bucket is already created 'bucketToUpload'. My code for upload a file is

```
require 'aws/aws-autoloader.php';

use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;
use Aws\S3\Enum\CannedAcl;


$bucket = 'bucketToUpload';
$pathToFile = getcwd().'/s3_upload_file.doc';

if(file_exists($pathToFile)) {

    try  {
        $client = S3Client::factory(array(
            'key'    => 'MYKEY',
            'secret' => 'MYSECRETKEY',
            'region' => 'us-west-1'
        ));

        $client->waitUntilBucketExists(array('Bucket' => $bucket)); 


        $result = $client->putObject(array(
                'Bucket'     => $bucket,
                'Key'        => 's3_upload_file.doc',
                'SourceFile' => getcwd(),
                'ACL'        => CannedAcl::PRIVATE_ACCESS,
                'Metadata'   => array(
                        'Foo' => 'abc',
                        'Baz' => '123'
                    )
                ));
      } catch (S3Exception $e) {
           echo "The file was not uploaded: " . $e->getMessage();
      }
    var_dump($result);      
}
```

I am getting Fatel error: Maximum execution time of 15 seconds exceeded.
Really don't know what am I doing wrong. Any help could be really appreciable.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I see a few things you may need to do.

*First*, you are specifying

```
'SourceFile' => getcwd(),
```

When I think you probably meant to do

```
'SourceFile' => $pathToFile,
```

*Second*, you are doing `var_dump($result);` which will probably not show you what you are expecting to see. Try `var_dump($result->toArray());` instead, but make sure to checkout the [user guide page about response models](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/guide/latest/feature-models.html) for more information about working with results.

*Third*, the error you are seeing `Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 15 seconds exceeded` is related to PHP's `max_execution_time` INI setting. You should increase that limit if needed. You can also use the [set_time_limit function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) within a single process.

I hope that helps!

Comment: I set 'SourceFile' => $pathToFile, used var_dump($result->toArray()); and set_time_limit(30); on first line of the script but still no luck.

Comment: Well, I figure out problem. In my php.ini file curl_mutli_exec was in disable_functions. I just make it enable and above script works fine.

Comment: Oh, that's interesting. What host are you on? That might be something the SDK docs should point out in an FAQ to watch out for.